# Evaluation of Clustering Performance in Satellite Image Segmentation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to do satellite image segmentation using K-means clustering in Python. I'm getting the image outputs for the 2,3 and 4 clusters with the original image correctly, but I need to calculate the Mutual Information scores to calculate the clustering performance. I wrote the following code for this but I am getting a size mismatch error between the original image and the segmented image. Can you help me where I made a mistake in the code below and how I can fix it?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import mutual_info_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def kmeans_segmentation(image, num_clusters):
   # Reshape image to a 2D array of pixels
   pixels = image.reshape(-1, 3)
   
   # Create K-Means object
   kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
   
   # Fit the K-Means model to the data
   kmeans.fit(pixels)
   
   # Get the cluster labels for each pixel
   labels = kmeans.labels_
   
   # Reshape the labels back to the original image shape
   segmented_image = labels.reshape(image.shape[:2])
   
   return segmented_image.astype(np.uint8), kmeans.cluster_centers_

# Load the satellite image
image = cv2.imread('300_L8.jpg')

# Convert image to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Perform K-Means Clustering for 2 clusters
segmented_image_2, centers_2 = kmeans_segmentation(image, num_clusters=2)

# Perform K-Means Clustering for 3 clusters
segmented_image_3, centers_3 = kmeans_segmentation(image, num_clusters=3)

# Perform K-Means Clustering for 4 clusters
segmented_image_4, centers_4 = kmeans_segmentation(image, num_clusters=4)

# Calculate Mutual Information scores
mi_score_2 = mutual_info_score(image.flatten(), segmented_image_2.flatten())
mi_score_3 = mutual_info_score(image.flatten(), segmented_image_3.flatten())
mi_score_4 = mutual_info_score(image.flatten(), segmented_image_4.flatten())

# Display the results
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(12, 4))
axs[0].imshow(image)
axs[0].set_title("Original Image")
axs[0].axis('off')
axs[1].imshow(segmented_image_2)
axs[1].set_title("2 Clusters (MI: {:.4f})".format(mi_score_2))
axs[1].axis('off')
axs[2].imshow(segmented_image_3)
axs[2].set_title("3 Clusters (MI: {:.4f})".format(mi_score_3))
axs[2].axis('off')
axs[3].imshow(segmented_image_4)
```